# How can one store a binary operator in a variable?

Tags: r, foreach, expression

I am pretty confused about the meaning of the `%Something%` operators.

How can one store a binary operator in a variable?

Something like...

```
binary_operator = store.binary(%in%)

c(3,9,4,1,7) binary_operator c(1:5) # would behave alike "c(3,9,4,1,7) %in% c(1:5)"
```

or something like

```
library(foreach)
binary_operator = expression(%do%) # or expression(%dopar%)
...
...
foreach (i=1:6) binary_operator { # would behave alike "foreach (i=1:6) %do% ..."
   ...
   ...
}
```

Comment: What is your expected outcome here?

Comment: Yeah, this needs to be fleshed out more. All functions in R can be stored in other data structures (e.g. lists) or re-assigned to other variables and called later...we need to know more about what you're trying to do.

Comment: If you want to define your own infix operator, it *must* begin and end with `%`.

Comment: I am expecting that the code `c(3,9,4,1,7) binary_operator c(1:5)` would be equivalent to `c(3,9,4,1,7) binary_operator c(1:5)`. I edited the question to clarify this point. Does it make sense?

Comment: This is what you are looking for? Redefine function `"%binary_operator%" = "%in%"` (Need to replace " with ' here) Call your function with infix notation `c(3,9,4,1,7) %binary_operator% c(1:5)` But note that infix functions are just regular R functions `"%binary_operator%"(c(3,9,4,1,7), c(1:5))`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to define your own infix operator, it *must* begin and end with `%`. This is so the parser knows how to properly pass the parameters to the function since it not the usual way code is parsed. Also, use the backtick to escape the percent signs in the variable name.

```
`%binary_operator%` <- `%in%`
c(3,9,4,1,7) %binary_operator% c(1:5)
```

Comment: Great, that answers my question. Thank you. I didn't know the term infix before. +1